# Read Client URL request from server socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am creating a Java Server using Socket. I would like to print the URL the client applciation requested when contacting the server. That is, if the client requests: https://your.server.com?usr=user_name, I would like to read this url from the server's end.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you *creating* a webserver from scratch, or are you using an existing webserver (like [Jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/))?

Comment: Yes, I am creating a webserver from scratch.

Comment: Is it the actual socket receiving/transmitting you have problem with, or parsing requests from clients?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like everyone is doing this these days ;)

Have a look at this guy, he is doing the same: [URL Parsing with Java server using Runnable class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003998/url-parsing-with-java-server-using-runnable-class)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have the complete url that client request.
Look at the HTTP protocol [RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html).
On the first line of your message you have

```
GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
```

so the first value is the request method and the second value is the part of the url without

```
http://myhost:myport
```

then in the header fields, sometimes, you can find only the host

```
Host: myhost
```